# hashcat token length exception

Tags: hashcat

Using pdf2john I get a hash like this:

`$pdf$2*3*128*2147483644*1*16*1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111*32*9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999`

According to the list of hashes this looks like type 10500. So I try the command

`hashcat -m 10500 -a 0 ./hash.txt`

which spits out the error

`Hashfile './hash.txt' on line 1 ($pdf$2...99999999999999999999999999999999): Token length exception`

where hash.txt simply contains the above hash. There is no whitespace at the end of my hash.txt file, so I'm at a loss as to what to try next.

Comment: have you tried with autodetection?

Comment: @liakoyras Just tried it, same error.

Comment: Did you copy pasted the hash or piped it into the file?

Comment: @liakoyras I tried two ways, first copy and paste, second pipe into a file but then use Nano editor to remove the unimportant parts of the hash that pdf2john spits out. Btw I am using the perl version of pdf2john.

Comment: While the example hash from the [Hashcat wiki](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=example_hashes) contains `-1028`, your hash includes `2147483644`  instead, being very close to the 32bit integer limit (2,147,483,647). This does not have to mean anything, but it could mean your pdf2john had an [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)